# Django + uWSGI via NGINX on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-11.10, uwsgi

I'm trying do deploy a django project. I tried a lot of tutorials, but had no luck. I use a new clean Ubuntu 11.10. I've performed

```
apt-get install nginx
apt-get install uwsgi
service nginx start
```

I've created folder `/deploy/project1` and put there `manage.py` and other files.

My current `/deploy/project1/project1/wsgi.py` contains:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project1.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

So, could you tell me how to deploy my django app for `domain.com` properly?

I've also installed Django via pip and easy_install

What should I add in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming that you have installed all requirement and you are using the aptitude packages then you don't need the wsgi.py.  All the configuration is in the uwsgi ini/xml/yaml file. (take the format that you prefer).

Here is a minimal example for `example.com` file for nginx(/etc/nginx/sites-available/examplecom for ubuntu 11.10)

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/projectname.log;
    location /media {
        alias /vagrant/test/projectname/media/;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /vagrant/test/projectname/static/;
    }
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/projectname/socket;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Create a symbolic link to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/examplecom /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/examplecom
```

or

```
sudo /usr/sbin/nxensite examplecom
```

You are done with NGINX.

Go to `/etc/uwsgi/apps-available` and create your ini file

```
sudo vim /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/projectname.ini

[uwsgi]
virtualenv=/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/projectenv
thread=3
master=1
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectname.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
chdir = /path/to/my/django/project
socket = /run/uwsgi/projectname/socket
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/projectname.log
```

Point your ini to /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/projectname.ini

```
sudo ln -s /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/projectname.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/projectname.ini
```

For more information, see any of these files on your system:

```
/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/README
/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/README
/usr/share/doc/uwsgi/README.Debian.gz
/etc/default/uwsgi
```

You are done. You can now restart nginx & uwsgi

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I've added an edit with some ubuntu specific items (nxensite, README for /etc/uwsgi/apps-*).

Comment: Why do you use: uwsgi_pass unix:///  with 3 slashes? Is there a different using 3 or 1 leading slashes??

Comment: There is no difference, 1 or 3 leading slashes stand for the full path to your unix socket.

Answer (score 9):

Do not forget that Debian's, Ubuntu's and its derivates' `uwsgi` package does not require installation of its Python plugin — `uwsgi-plugin-python`, because uWSGI does not necessarily uses only Python (there are plugins for Lua, Erlang and other languages). However, Django requires Python plugin. Install it:

```
sudo apt install uwsgi-plugin-python
```

Unlike PIP's installation, you should explicitly mention uwsgi's plugin used in the app's config by adding a `plugins = python` line to it (if you use Python), like this:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python
uwsgi-socket = /var/sockets/django.sock
chmod-socket = 660
chdir = /home/v/django
module = project.wsgi
```

Unless you do this, there will be no Python-specific options available. And Debian's/Ubuntu's uWSGI will be just quiet about it!

Comment: `plugin = python`, I think. You wouldn't *believe* how many places neglect to bring this up at all.  I was migrating a python app from 1 server (which was working 100%) to another in hosted in a different location, and while I'd obviously done this ages, and ages ago, I'd completely forgotten about it.  When looking for information about a uwsgi python app ini file, most places tell you to just remove the "plugin" line altogether, none mention to check to make sure that `uwsgi-plugin-python` is installed on the system.

Comment: From `man uwsgi`: `--plugins — load uWSGI plugins; --plugin — load uWSGI plugins`, so these two parameters are effectively synonyms.