# uwsgi: find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory

Tags: uwsgi

I am trying to start uwsgi for the first time and I am getting an error:

```
sudo service uwsgi start --status-all
* Starting app server(s) uwsgi
dirname: invalid option -- '-'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
basename: invalid option -- '-'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
find: `/etc/uwsgi/s-enabled': No such file or directory
```

The *only* steps I have taken towards installing uwsgi is apt-get install.

Then I created a .ini file for my site in the /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/ directory and a symbiotic link to this .ini file in /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/ directory.

I haven't the slightest clue why it is checking in /etc/uwsgi/s-enabled/ directory.

Comment: What version uwsgi are you running?  Run "uwsgi --version" to check.  Installing through apt gives you an old version, 1.1 I think. Installing via pip will get you version 1.9.  Can you post your /etc/init/uwsgi.conf file.

Comment: My version is uWSGI 1.0.3-debian. Which is strange since it's Ubuntu. I will try via pip.

Comment: I installed it via pip (had to install python-dev to compile it). Then I did apt-get remove uwsgi. When I type uwsgi --version is still returns uWSGI 1.0.3-debian

Comment: pip installs to /usr/bin/local/uwsgi, try typing "/usr/bin/local/uwsgi --version" it should return 1.9.  Then just update the BINPATH line in your /etc/init/uwsgi file to "env BINPATH=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your uwsgi config file, it should probably be

> /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled

this directory holds the uwsgi app's ini files either via symlinks from directory

> /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/

or you can have ini files directly here.

example with symlink:

```
ln -s /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/testApp.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/testApp.ini
```

Installation of uwsgi and it's configuration on ubuntu can be found here

[django + uwssgi + nginx on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453828/django-uwsgi-via-nginx-on-ubuntu-11-10)

Installation of same on centOS6 can be found here

[uwsgi + gevent + flask + nginx + mongodb on centOS6](http://www.leeladharan.com/installation-of-nginx-mongodb-uwsgi-gevent-and-flask-on-centos-6)